# Failed to specialize function template compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I have a template vector class, and I am trying to overload the arithmetic operators such that adding/subtracting vectors of different primitive types will yield a vector of the primitive type returned by the arithmetic operation (i.e., adding a vector of int and a vector of double will yield a vector of double).  The relevant code follows:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
private:
T x, y, z;

public:
   // constructors, destructors, etc.

   T X() const { return ( this->x ); }
   T Y() const { return ( this->y ); }
   T Z() const { return ( this->z ); }

   template<typename U> auto operator+(const Vector<U> &v) const -> Vector<decltype(this->x + v.X())>
   {
       return ( Vector<decltype(this->x + v.X())>( this->x + v.X(), this->y + v.Y(), this->z + v.Z() ) );
   }
};
```

Then, in main.cpp:

```
Vector<double> d1(1,2,3), d2(4,5,6);
std::cout << d1 + d2;
```

I get the following error from Visual Studio 2012:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'Vector<T> Vector<double>::operator +(const Vector<U> &) const'

with
[
T=unknown
]

With the following template arguments:

'double'

error C2676: binary '+' : 'Vector<T>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

with
[
T=double
]
```

Please advise.

Comment: Try to upgrade to visual-studio-2013. works with gcc (https://ideone.com/GlJOcE)

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ fails to determine the correct type of your `decltype` expression. By replacing your expression with `decltype(*((T*)0) + *((U*)0))` you remove the dependency on `this` and the argument `v`, which leads to the intended result on VS as well.

Note: Bug was reproducable on VS2013.4 on which the fix was tested as well.

Comment: Thank you!  That works.  I am confused by the expression you have here;  can you explain its meaning?

Comment: @LRC It dereferences a (null) pointer of appropriate type to create an lvalue of `T` and `U` respectively. This way, they need not be constructible in any specific way.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  That makes perfect sense!

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>())` seems more readable.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree, I was just too lazy to figure out if `declval` was supported on VS2012 already.